# Configuring bluetooth on beagleboneblack with cc2564moda using Qt

Tags: linux, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy, beagleboneblack, bluez

I'm trying to develop an application on **Bluetooth Low Energy Peripheral** based on **Qt 5.7** on **beaglebone-black** using **UART** module **CC2564MODA**.
I'm able to advertise LE device & created services and characteristics.
Using **BLE Scanner** Application to realize implementation.
While trying to pair my peripheral with any device Linux kernel prints

**Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available**

Where Linux kernel contains **BlueZ v 5.41** .

I can see my services & all characteristics with pairing option.
But i wanted to add 4 pin pairing method.
Where i can set pin code.

Is there any article to study or any standard method to resolve this issue.

Thanks